# Shrink-wrap into holes, cracks and crevices

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap

I have a messy mesh that was generated in python. Think a sphere with lots of crevices, cracks, and holes (there is also an interior topology that is not important). I want to disregard the interior and fill in the holes (in an approximate fashion). An ideal solution would be something like the shrink wrap modifier, but such that it "goes into" the holes with respect to some threshold. I can then tweak the threshold to get the effect that I am after.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! Could you please add some images to show your mesh and what you would like to do? It is somewhat difficult to imagine what you are trying to do. You can take screenshots of the Blender window by going to *Window > Save Screenshot*.